# SDRAM: Why CAS latency is configurable

Tags: timing, sdram

I've seen a couple of very similar questions but the answers don't answer my question:

[DDR2 CAS Latency - is it fixed to clock-cycles or time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82678/ddr2-cas-latency-is-it-fixed-to-clock-cycles-or-time)

[What limits the lower bound of DRAM CAS latency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333031/what-limits-the-lower-bound-of-dram-cas-latency)

In my current understanding once a row in DRAM bank has been activated then it's just a matter of the values registered on the amplifiers to be latched out to the output and this process is synchronized by the clock, so it should be specified in clock cycles how long it takes to read a column from an active row.

Yet it appears CAS is time-based, e.g. [this datasheet](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/128mb_x4x8x16_sdram.pdf) has CAS=1 for 166MHz, CAS=2 for 100MHz, CAS=3 for 50MHz and has CAS configurable, which in my understanding should be a constant number of clock cycles regardless of the clock frequency.

What is wrong with my understanding? What analog process the column reads in DRAM depend on?

**Edit:** researching on this a bit more I've found there's t_CAC, the time between the CAS pin is driven low and valid data is available on the data pins. Then t_CAS is always measured in a whole number of clock cycles and should be t_CAS >= t_CAC.
This makes me think the read process is actually asynchronous with purely combinational logic in between the sense amplifiers and the CAS pin and the data pins. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6):

Inside the SDRAM chip, the actual CAS latency requirement is a combinatorial time delay, independent of the external interface's clock period. It may help to think of it as an old-fashioned asynchronous DRAM chip "wrapped" in a synchronous interface.

Since the bus master (CPU) can choose the interface clock speed, it makes sense to also allow it to configure the number of clocks to use for CAS latency, in order to get the best performance without dropping below the amount of time the chip requires internally.

Comment: I understand this, but the question is why this delay is independent of the external clock. Is this because there is an internal clock with a different set frequency independent of the external clock frequency.

Comment: No, there is no other "internal" clock. The actual RAM array is asynchronous.

Comment: I understand that before and during a row activation it's asynchronous, but when a row is active and we're reading from the active row, is't this read process all synchronous?

Comment: No. CAS latency is associated with the last part of the asynchronous row-reading process -- basically, selecting at what time to capture the data coming out of the column sense amplifiers. Clocking out the data after that is synchronous, but that isn't what CAS latency is about.

Comment: @axk The whole row is fetched (asynchronously) to an iternal buffer. When you then read data (synchronously) from the SDRAM chip, you are actually accessing that buffer.

Comment: Does it mean that when a CAS latency is configured for an SDRAM chip it uses this to calculate the number of cycles it should delay the read from the sense amplifiers by on top of the constant number of cycles needed to latch out the data? E.g. CL=3 may mean it would wait for 2 clock cycles before reading the data from the amplifiers and then it would take 1 clock cycle to latch the data out?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question, and we're starting to stray from the original question anyway. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here? The SDRAM chip doesn't "calculate" anything; you're telling it what timing to use, and if you use the wrong values with respect to your clock speed, you won't be able to read your data reliably.

Comment: Just trying to understand how it works, this is not necessary to successfully control SDRAM, I'm sure.

Comment: In the datasheet you cited, the block diagram and operational descriptions are pretty clear. Note how the minimum clock period varies with the CL setting -- this gives you a clue about the internal access time.